# Consulta sql entre dos tablas en MYSQL

Tags: php, sql

Muy Buenos dias y Buenas tardes todos les explico tengo una duda acerca de una consulta SQL. Basicamente es una consulta que podria resolverse con un INNER JOIN o como puede que no. Tengo dos tablas en mysql una llamada **t_historial_activo** y otra **t_usuario** ambas se encuentran relacionadas.

**t_usuario**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**t_historial_activo**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta simplemente es una consulta SQL de `SELECT * FROM t_historial_activo WHERE codigo_mh='22152215'` a la tabla t_historial_activo
pero no puedo traer el campo **nom_completo** de la tabla t_usuario.
**Ambas tablas estan relacionadas t_usuario.ci  y t_historial_activo.ci_funcionario_de , t_historial_activo.a_funcionario** 
En vez  de traer los campos ci_funcionario_de  y  a_funcionario quiero traer el campo nom_completo  donde esta los nombres respectivamente a los que pertencen esos usuarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La consulta que realize fue la siguiente `SELECT t_historial_activo.codigo_mh,t_usuario.nom_completo,t_historial_activo.fechayhora,t_historial_activo.tipo,t_usuario.nom_completo FROM t_historial_activo INNER JOIN t_usuario ON t_usuario.ci=t_historial_activo.a_ci_funcionario OR t_usuario.ci=t_historial_activo.ci_funcionario_de WHERE codigo_mh='22152215'`
dando como resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pienso que es una consulta conmpuesta de UNION,
Gracias de por leer y si pueden ayudarme. les agradeceria bastante. =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT hist.codigo_mh, ude.nom_completo, hist.fechayhora, hist.tipo, ua.nom_completo 
FROM t_historial_activo hist 
INNER JOIN t_usuario ua ON ua.ci=hist.a_ci_funcionario 
INNER JOIN t_usuario ude ON ude.ci=hist.ci_funcionario_de 
WHERE hist.codigo_mh='22152215'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudo bastante tu respuesta

Comment: @Rudy ¿Era justo lo que estabas buscando? Si es así marca la respuesta como correcta, si no dime que buscabas exactamente.

Comment: Si es justo la respuesta correcta Gracias Amigo